# What does the word "Shem" mean in Genesis 11:4?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach

I know that "Shem" literally means "name" in Hebrew. But what did the people of the earth mean by "let us make ourselves a name/shem, lest we be scattered upon the face of the earth" ([Genesis 11:4](http://chabad.org/8175#v=4))?

Since making themselves a name would prevent them from scattering, there must be something more than just reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadal on Genesis 11:4:2:

> ונעשה לנו שם: הבאים אחרינו יהללו אותנו על המעשה הגדול הזה, או העיר עם
>   המגדל הם עצמם שם, כלומר דבר מצויין ומפורסם (Monumento), ואולי ככה ויעש
>   דוד שם בשובו מהכותו את ארם (שמואל ב' ח' י"ג), ואולי ככה וקברו כל עם
>   הארץ והיה להם לשם (יחזקאל ל"ט י"ג) קבורת המון גוג תהיה דבר מצויין
>   ומפורסם.

(The text comes from sefaria.org, and I'm uncertain about the English word "Monumento" here.)

My paraphrasing of above:

Those that follow us will praise us on this great thing (the tower) that we made. Or, it could mean that the city itself is a "name", that is, it is something excellent and famous (noteworthy).

He cites II Samuel 8:13:

> וַיַּ֤עַשׂ דָּוִד֙ שֵׁ֔ם בְּשֻׁב֕וֹ מֵהַכּוֹת֥וֹ אֶת־אֲרָ֖ם
>   בְּגֵיא־מֶ֑לַח שְׁמוֹנָ֥ה עָשָׂ֖ר אָֽלֶף׃
>
> And David got him a name when he returned from smiting the Arameans in
>   the Valley of Salt, even eighteen thousand men

The term שֵׁ֔ם is used, here, too. Sefaria translates this as "name", which is not totally accurate.

Metzudat David on II Samuel 8:13:1:

> **ויעש דוד שם .** עשה גבורה גדולה , וקנה שם :

He showed great bravery and acquired reputation.
.

Comment: Zecharia Sitchin and other archeologists says that Shem sometimes indicates monument according to near eastern manuscripts from Sumer and the like.

Comment: @mil I think that one of the other commentaries (possibly Sforno) echoes that notion as well.

Comment: @mil, like "_yad vashem_", perhaps? Cf. _yad Avshalom_.

Comment: @msh210 I don't know what do you mean. And Zecharia Sitchin sometimes goes further in some of his books -which is considered a hoax by some- to hint that it's like a rocket ship ( I am not taking it seriously but I have to mention everything I heard of).

Comment: @msh210 I'm also lost at your intention. The word "yad" in your two examples means "monument", not the word "shem". As for "Yad Vashem", I think this name is taken from *Yeshayahu* - the chapter that we read on most fast days during *mincha*. I think there too, it means "something noteworthy".

Comment: @DanF, I was referring to that verse, and didn't check the commentaries before posting my comment; its hesitancy ("perhaps?") was due to my not knowing whether anyone explains _shem_ in that verse in that way.